# How to define React component with conditional props interface?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, field, tsx

i need to define "Field" component that renders `textarea` or `input` depends on prop `multiline`

I trying to do this like that:

```js
import React from 'react';

type Props<T extends boolean = boolean> = { multiline: T } & T extends true 
    ? React.HTMLProps<HTMLTextAreaElement> 
    : React.HTMLProps<HTMLInputElement>

export const Field: React.FC<Props> = ({ multiline, ...props }) => { // error here
    const Element = multiline ? 'textarea' : 'input';

    return <Element {...props} onInput={e => {}} />; // error here
}

// usage

const result = (
    <Field onChange={e => console.log(e.target.value)} /> // error here
);
```

But typescript provide several errors like:

```
1 Property 'multiline' does not exist on type 'HTMLProps<HTMLInputElement> & { children?: ReactNode; }'.(2339)

2 [large error, more in playground]

3 Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.(2339)
```

[Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgAUcwBnAHgBU4kAPGJAHYATFnABGECABtUAuAF5xkmSgEA%20BXADecEAFcpMYFOACkALjhcAvnABkV7n0Ei4MKHvrk4PuAH5EYhgAOgAJDgBZABkmCFY2cOiOXhgAQSIUAFEZEEEYDW9fS2R0EMSY5nZygEkBMD0YbKRcgXzKXkhYODQIARZ4ADFgJCkhYqDggYBhNljWDUUACh19Q2NTJAAaOGDdsEq4awBKBQ0tQp8evvgmlvhFVaMTM38Cfj4UDPw4S3xTepgZEovjgRBgeigcjYtzy2l2wX2cRYtgA9GoKNZKCiUXA9CwUABzJCUK79UFIFgGe5wRYXOBsIYjIRwXpTAAWqiJ8i09HkGlJ0iQwSkEAJiyFME%20RJCADcUFJPEdUWpyEcKOQgA)

How can i define such component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem: No `T` in Field

You have defined a generic type `Props` that depends on `T` but your component is not generic.  It always takes `Props<boolean>` which resolves to the `HTMLInputElement` props because `boolean extends true` is `false`.  The reason `{multiline: boolean}` is getting lost is because you need parentheses around the rest of your type.

#### React.HTMLProps

When using your `React.HTMLProps` typings I didn't get errors when assigning mismatched properties like `type="number"` to a `textarea` or `rows={5}` to an `input`.  The more restrictive types are `JSX.IntrinsicElements['textarea']` and `JSX.IntrinsicElements['input']` (which resolve to a type like `React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.TextareaHTMLAttributes<HTMLTextAreaElement>, HTMLTextAreaElement>`).  If you want strict enforcement then use these!  This also makes the `e` value in the `onChange` callback get the correct type based on the element.

#### Implementation

When using a generic component with restrictive types, we now get an error in the implementation on `return <Element {...props} />;`  I thought that breaking it into two (`return multiline ? <textarea {...props} /> : <input {...props}/>;`) would help but we still get errors.  Conditionals are rough.  You can use `as` assertions to fix things.  I'm generally ok with making assertions in the implementation of a function when the usage of it stays strictly typed.  So you can do this:

```
type Props<T extends boolean = boolean> = { multiline: T } & (T extends true
    ? JSX.IntrinsicElements['textarea']
    : JSX.IntrinsicElements['input'])

export const Field = <T extends boolean>({ multiline, ...props }: Props<T>) => {
    const Element = multiline ? 'textarea' : 'input';

    return <Element {...props as any} />;
}
```

[Playground #1](https://tsplay.dev/wj55YW)

#### Union Type

We can avoid having to make assertions by typing `Props` as a union of two situations.  This allows us to check which type in the union we have by looking at `props.multiline`.  This gets messy though because you cannot desctructure until **after** you have discriminated the union, but we don't want to pass multiline through to the DOM.

This code passes all type checks, but it needs additional work to prevent passing `multiline` through to the DOM.

```
type Props = ( 
    { multiline: true } & JSX.IntrinsicElements['textarea'] | 
    { multiline: false } & JSX.IntrinsicElements['input']
);

export const Field = ({ ...props }: Props) => {
    return props.multiline ? <textarea {...props} /> : <input {...props}/>
}
```

[Playground #2](https://tsplay.dev/weeeEw)

#### Usage

Either way the usage is very strongly typed!  Our `onChange` callback gets the correct type like `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>` and we get error if passing `textarea` props when `multiline={false}` or vice-versa.

```
<Field
    onChange={e => console.log(e.target.value)} // e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>
    multiline={true}
    rows={5} // ok
    type="number" // error
/>
<Field
    onChange={e => console.log(e.target.value)} // e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
    multiline={false}
    type="number" // ok
    rows={5} // error
/>
```

Comment: Awesome answer! But maybe you know: how can i use this with forwardRef?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be using an intersection of the 2 types, so it can be either/or. So for `Props` type use the '&' operator to cover both input types, then in the `onChange` event use it again for each input type event (since it can be either). Something like this:

```
import React from 'react';

type Props<T extends boolean = boolean> = { multiline?: T } &
    React.HTMLProps<HTMLTextAreaElement> &
    React.HTMLProps<HTMLInputElement>;

export const Field: React.FC<Props> = ({ multiline, ...props }) => {
    const Element = multiline ? 'textarea' : 'input';

    return <Element {...props} />;
}

// usage

const result = (
    <Field onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> & React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => (
        console.log(e.target.value)
    )} />
);
```